# Overlay 2 pdf files by each page using pymupdf

Tags: python, pdf, merge, overlay, pymupdf

I need to combine (merge/overlay) 2 pdf files like second on first by each page. I've tried the code

```py
import fitz

doc1 = fitz.open(background)
doc2 = fitz.open(only_text_path)
doc1.insertPDF(doc2)
```

but it only concatenates doc1 + doc2, doesn't overlay

Is where a way to do this using `fitz` (pymupdf library)?

I found a code with `PyPDF2`, but it works slow and not so stable:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

output = PdfFileWriter()
with open(background, "rb") as f:
     empty_pdf = PdfFileReader(f)
     with open(only_text_path, 'rb') as f2:
        text_pdf = PdfFileReader(f2)
        for i in range(empty_pdf.getNumPages()):
           empty_page = empty_pdf.getPage(i)
           text_page = text_pdf.getPage(i)
           empty_page.mergePage(text_page)
           output.addPage(empty_page)
        with open(merge_result_path, "wb") as out_pdf:
           output.write(out_pdf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @KJ

I used this code, it's working

```py
    doc1 = fitz.open(empty_path)
    doc2 = fitz.open(only_text_path)

    for i in range(doc1.page_count):
        page = doc1.load_page(i)
        page_front = fitz.open()
        page_front.insert_pdf(doc2, from_page=i, to_page=i)
        page.show_pdf_page(page.rect, page_front, pno=0, keep_proportion=True, overlay=True, oc=0, rotate=0, clip=None)

    doc1.save(merge_result_path, encryption=fitz.PDF_ENCRYPT_KEEP)
```